# Change the default Statistical test performed by "add_p()" function in gtsummary summary tables

Tags: gtsummary

I am using gtsummary package to generate summary tables.

I would like to do the following:

1. That the "add_p" function **performs a two-proportions z-test for the proportions** in the "by" variable instead of chi-square test for independence. Using stats::prop.test
2. Displays on the footnote that the "Statistical tests performed" are "2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction"

How can I do that within this example code?

```
trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, grade)
trial3 <- trial2[-which(trial2$grade == "III"),]
trial4 <- droplevels(trial3)

trial4 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2,
    label = grade ~ "Tumor Grade"
  ) %>% add_p()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two options. First, build a custom p-value function to calculate the p-value based off of `prop.test()`. There is an example of this in the `add_p.tbl_summary()` help file.

The second option (and easier option) is to download the current development version of the package from GitHub. In this version, the `prop.test()` option is already built in.  Example below!

```r
remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] ‘1.3.5.9017’

trial %>%
  select(response, death, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p(test = everything() ~ "prop.test") %>%
  modify_footnote(p.value ~ "2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction")
```

[image]

You may also want to check out the new function `add_difference()` that also reports the `prop.test()` p-value along with differences between groups.

```r
trial %>%
  select(trt, response, death) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              statistic = all_dichotomous() ~ "{p}%",
              missing = "no") %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ NA) %>%
  add_n() %>%
  add_difference(estimate_fun = ~paste0(style_sigfig(. * 100), "%"))
```

[image]

Comment: The add_difference function is actually very useful! Thank you very much for the prompt response @Daniel!